# From a single-column of strings, take those that are related and put them onto their own rows in a data frame using dplyr / tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

I imported a tab-delimited text file using read.table to make a data frame with a single column of text strings. The top 3 strings are related, the next 3 strings are related, etc. I would like to put related strings on their own row in another data frame. I would like to know if there is an easier way to do this using dplyr / tidyverse than the way I did it using a loop, as I show below.

First, to create the data,
initialize df.txt:

```
df.txt <- data.frame(col.of.tex= character(9), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then, create df.txt, a data frame consisting of a single column of character strings with every three being related:

```
j <- seq(from = 1, to = 9, by = 3)
for(i in seq(j)) {
        df.txt[j[i],] <- paste0("No.Abstract", i)
        df.txt[j[i]+1,] <- paste0("Title.Abstract", i)
        df.txt[j[i]+2,] <- paste0("Abstract", i)
}
```

Then put the strings from df.txt that are related (i.e., groups of three strings) on the same rows in the data frame df.inRows:

```
    for(i in 1:3) {
            df.inRows[i,1] <- df.txt[j[i],]
            df.inRows[i,2] <- df.txt[j[i]+1,]
            df.inRows[i,3] <- df.txt[j[i]+2,]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution. The key realisations are that you can create an ID on which to `group_by`, that you can use `str_c(collapse)` to concatenate a character vector into one vector, and then that you can use `separate` to split a string into multiple columns. This relies on your groups-of-three pattern holding; if there is a more robust way to form the groups I would use that (for example if you can get the group id from the values of `col.of.tex` somehow.

```r
df.txt <- data.frame(col.of.tex= character(9), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
j <- seq(from = 1, to = 9, by = 3)
for(i in seq(j)) {
  df.txt[j[i],] <- paste0("No.Abstract", i)
  df.txt[j[i]+1,] <- paste0("Title.Abstract", i)
  df.txt[j[i]+2,] <- paste0("Abstract", i)
}

library(tidyverse)
df.txt %>%
  mutate(group_id = rep(1:3, each = 3)) %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  summarise(group = str_c(col.of.tex, collapse = "_")) %>%
  separate(group, c("No.Abstract", "Title.Abstract", "Abstract"), sep = "_")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   group_id No.Abstract  Title.Abstract  Abstract 
#>      <int> <chr>        <chr>           <chr>    
#> 1        1 No.Abstract1 Title.Abstract1 Abstract1
#> 2        2 No.Abstract2 Title.Abstract2 Abstract2
#> 3        3 No.Abstract3 Title.Abstract3 Abstract3
```

Created on 2018-04-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Great. Thanks for replying so fast. Now I understand.